# iOS Keyboard Extension(App Groups)

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-app-group, ios-keyboard-extension

i have a question about `Keyboard Extension`.

Container app has many images.(ex > 100 images and total 100MB)
and container app has saved using `NSUserDefaults`.

**like this:**

```
NSMutableArray* arr = [NSMutableArray new];

for(NSInteger i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    UIImage* img = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"img%ld",i]];
    NSData* data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    [arr addObject:data]
}

NSUserDefaults* ud = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"<group identifier>"];
[ud setObject:arr forKey:@"image_data"];
[ud synchronize];
```

and keyboard app gets image data from `NSUserDefaults`.

**Is it right way that container app send heavy size data to keyboard app?**

In special case, when `NSUserDefaults` instance accesses method(objectForKey:) in keyboard app,  keyboard app crashed.

**The special case is :**

if image data size in `NSUserDefaults` is bigger than about 30MB(not sure), keyboard app crashed and if the size is smaller than about 30MB,  it works well.

**Is there max size limit of NSUserDefaults?**

i just want like [this app](https://popkey.co/).

i want to know that i control heavy size data in keyboard app.

Comment: if you want to save image then save in core data than NSUserdefault

Comment: can keyboard app access core data that container app save?

Answer (score 1):

1) First you have to write image in Shared document directory.

```
- (NSString *)getSharedLocationPath:(NSString *)appGroupName {
    NSURL *groupContainerURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:@"group.yourGroupName"];
    return [groupContainerURL relativePath];
}
```

2) Write Image to above shared Directory.

```
    NSString *path = [[self getSharedLocationPath:@"group.yourGroupName"] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",images]];
   //Here fileData is your Image data.
   [fileData writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

3) Exactly get this path to Keyboard Extension class same as above.

```
- (NSString *)getSharedLocationPath:(NSString *)appGroupName {
    NSURL *groupContainerURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:@"group.yourGroupName"];
    return [groupContainerURL relativePath];
}
//Here get content of directory from shared document directory. 
NSArray *directoryContent = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:[self getSharedLocationPath:@"group.yourGroupName"] error:NULL];
    for (Count = 0; Count < (int)[directoryContent count]; Count++)
    {
        NSLog(@"File %d: %@", (Count + 1), [directoryContent objectAtIndex:Count]);
    }
//Now you get your images from app shared directory.
```

Comment: oh! i do not know shared path.  i will try this. thanks thanks

Comment: shared path is used for two app for shared data between it from document directory.

Comment: Here @"group.yourGroupName" replace with your extension app group name.

Comment: Plz if you satisfied with my answer then up vote or approved my answer. thank you.